# Wordpress swipebox album lighbox always jumps to raw image file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I have a super annoying issue in a latest Wordpress site: a Lightbox swipe box is used there and nothing else is installed. When you click on an image it always opens the slideshow for a blink of a second and then jumps to the image file directly. It is super annoying and after tons of search I could not find the issue.

https://brickmonkey.net/jokers-carnival-wagon-jocka-bot/

I never had that type of issue with Lightbox on photo albums in Wordpress, because it is super standard and nothing modded here.

Somebody had a some issue or knows a solution for this awkward bug?

Thank you!

EDIT: solution found: seems the direct link tracking interferes with query lightboxes. Solution was to disable the direct link tracking.

Comment: It works fine here? have you fixed it?

Comment: yes, thank you! I found a wired influence from my site tracking code: it seems that the direct link tracking option via javascript influences all the Lightbox behaviors....so I just turned that off....but never had that before. Thanks for helping investigating!